# iOS Enterprise -- Install Fails/Inconsistent

Tags: ios, ios-enterprise

I've been having some trouble installing enterprise builds. The installer seems to be inconsistent on phones not linked to my dev account.

For instance, the build seems to install on 9 out of 10 phones/ipods.  I've checked for dumb mistakes like not supporting lower operating systems.

- Is there any restrictions imposed by the carriers?
  AT&T vs Verzion vs Sprint
- Is there any complications caused by Jailbreaking?
- Does using a Wildcard Distribution Profile introduce problems?

Has anyone else experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution that fixed it for me was making sure there was `no device plugged in` when I built the enterprise signed archive.

Update: I wrote a post about it [here](http://mwhuss.com/enterprise-builds-won-t-install)